# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' can't decode byte

Tags: python, c, sockets, character-encoding

I have written a simple client/server socket program, where the server part is in C language whereas the client is in python. I am very much able to send the data from the client to the server but cannot send a response message/data back to the python script..

server.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , new_socket , c, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client ;
    char *message;
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char *hello = "Hello from server";
    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("bind failed");
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    if (new_socket<0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
    }

    puts("Connection accepted\n");

    valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
 send(new_socket, hello, strlen(hello),0);
    printf("Socket: Sent data!\n");

    write(new_socket, "Some message", 1024);

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I run the server and the client, I am able to connect them and send data to the server but the response to be sent back cannot be decoded by the client and gives me the following traceback call...

```
Sending "This is the message. It will be repeated."
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonclient.py", line 35, in <module>
    client_program()
  File "pythonclient.py", line 25, in client_program
    text += data.decode().strip()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfb in position 44: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Have you tried not using the b's when reading from the socket in the python file? Apparently you're expecting binary values, not unicode. I may be wrong, just try it.

Comment: just did and it returns me, `must be str, not tuple` traceback call.

Comment: did you print the tuple?

Comment: Yes i did, and following was the result 
`(<function client_program.<locals>.read_socket at 0x7fb1ae69ea60>, b'')
(<function client_program.<locals>.read_socket at 0x7fb1ae69eae8>, b'')
(<function client_program.<locals>.read_socket at 0x7fb1ae69ea60>, b'')
(<function client_program.<locals>.read_socket at 0x7fb1ae69eae8>, b'')^C`

With the following traceback call when i stop it with Ctrl+C

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonclient.py", line 35, in <module>
    client_program()
  File "pythonclient.py", line 25, in client_program
    print(data)
KeyboardInterrupt`

Comment: Why are you defining `read_socket` on every iteration through the `while` loop? I would think you could just do `data = client_socket.recv(1024)`.

Comment: I really dont understand the meaning of this, but all that I can make-out is that it is returning me a function from the python file only which should be the message sent from the C server instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your Client.py and it seems works well, but when I send hex `0xfb`, the program crushed like that, so I think your server part sends invalid data, which is not in `utf-8` format.

I suggest you to put a debug code like this:

```
data = b''.join(iter(read_socket, b''))
print(bytes(data))
text += data.decode().strip()
```

so you can see what bytes you sent and find the invalid data, that your server sends.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> write(new_socket, "Some message", 1024);
> ```

Since "Some message" is less than 1024 byte the server will send "Some message" and then junk data to the client, i.e. whatever is in memory after this message buffer until the length of 1024 bytes is reached. The chance is high that the junk data contain byte combinations which are not valid utf-8 in which case the Python application will fail to decode the data as UTF-8.